# Using a R-134a vacuum pump and manifold set to service a home A/C with R-410a

Tags: hvac

I'm fairly comfortable working on automotive R-134a air conditioners but haven't worked on a home R-410a system before. I have a manifold gauge set, charge hoses, and electric vacuum pump.

I know I will need new charge hoses because the fittings are different but can I re-use the manifold set and vacuum pump?

I'm also planning on getting certified for EPA Section 608 so I can legally buy refrigerant.

Comment: So what are the respective refrigerant temperatures and pressures?

Comment: Rules have changed. It's not enough to sit a class and take a test.  You must now also have recovery equipment, and also a supply chain/vendor relationships to return the recovered refrigerant into for destruction/recycling.